# Is it possible to migrate Drupal 6 core profile fields into the new profile fields in D7?

Tags: php, drupal, data-migration

I´m trying to upgrade a big D6 site to D7.

I have the content profile module installed.

I have a few core profile fields that I need to keep.

The "profile" node that was created by the content profile module, has no fields in it. I just used in order to manage in a better way the theming and presentation of profiles.

I´ve installed Profile2 module. I´ve installed the profile page submodule that comes bundled with it.

**1.** I would like to export or convert all those core profile fields into the new entity fields in D7. **How may I do that?**

**2.** In the meanwhile (in case number 1 is just not possible at all), I´ve tried theming the ***profile2.tpl.php*** file, trying to print into it my old core profile fields.

I´ve [followed the instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1488468) to print those core profile fields, so I´ve harcoded this `print check_plain($account->profile_nombre);` into the template, but it doesn´t print the name of the user that´s inserted into the *nombre* field (core profile field). So, how may I theme the profile page?

I´ve watched [this video tutorial](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-profile-2-module) also, about the profile2 module, but I´m still absolutely clueless on how to manage profiles in D7 when you already have a couple thousand users with core profile fields in it.

***Please note that I´ve tried using the "migrate" module, and the "drupal 2 drupal" migration module, with no luck.***

Thanks for your help and insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution might be to use Feeds module (to import to fields) and Views Data Export Module (to export fields to the spreadsheet). The procedure would be:

1. Setup a view that lists all of your users and displays all of the fields you want to migrate. Then add news display (data export) and choose CSV format.
2. Use feeds to import the data to D7. Just map each exported field to a new field.

This might seem complicated at first, but it's really simple and should work.

Comment: THANKS!!! You´re the first person to tell me a real, tangible idea about how to do this!! Many, many thanks. I´ll try to do it right away!!